# cant delete a folder using deletefile command

Tags: delphi

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not deletefile('c:\test') then
  raiselastoserror
end;
```

i get os error 5 : access denied
when i use the same code to delete a file say wwj.txt it works fine but doesnt work for folders what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the RemoveDir() procedure instead. Make sure it is not a current directory for your app, or any other too, or it will remain. SysUtils must be used to get the function.

If you need to, delete the contents of the directory first (below). Recursive deleting is possible, and consider the implications of the '.' test if you use directories or files with '.'.

```
procedure DeleteFiles( szDBDirectory : string );
var
    szFile : string;
    SearchRec: TSearchRec;
    szSearchPath : string;
    nResult : integer;
begin
    szSearchPath := szDBDirectory;
    nResult := FindFirst(szSearchPath + '\*.*', faAnyFile, SearchRec);
    try
        while 0 = nResult do
        begin
            if('.' <> SearchRec.Name[1]) then
            begin
                szFile := szSearchPath + '\' + SearchRec.Name;
{$IFDEF DEBUG_DELETE}
                CodeSite.Send('Deleting "' + szFile + '"');
{$ENDIF}
                FileSetAttr(szFile, 0);
                DeleteFile(szFile);
            end;

            nResult := FindNext(SearchRec);
        end;
    finally
        FindClose(SearchRec);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: I've added code that will delete contents first. You could merge them into one easily.

Comment: but can we not use deletefile to delete directory somehow i saw this on a german site and author used it to delete a folder

Comment: I suspect that the DeleteFile you saw was a custom version which did what this code does. You can do the same - just make sure that your unit is last in the Uses clause.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the shell functions. According to [delphi.about.com](http://delphi.about.com/cs/adptips1999/a/bltip1199_2.htm), this will delete nonempty folders even if they contain subfolders:

```
uses ShellAPI;
Function DelTree(DirName : string): Boolean;
var
  SHFileOpStruct : TSHFileOpStruct;
  DirBuf : array [0..255] of char;
begin
  try
   Fillchar(SHFileOpStruct,Sizeof(SHFileOpStruct),0) ;
   FillChar(DirBuf, Sizeof(DirBuf), 0 ) ;
   StrPCopy(DirBuf, DirName) ;
   with SHFileOpStruct do begin
    Wnd := 0;
    pFrom := @DirBuf;
    wFunc := FO_DELETE;
    fFlags := FOF_ALLOWUNDO;
    fFlags := fFlags or FOF_NOCONFIRMATION;
    fFlags := fFlags or FOF_SILENT;
   end; 
    Result := (SHFileOperation(SHFileOpStruct) = 0) ;
   except
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: but is it that deletefile is not for deleting folders or am i using it incorrectly?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the function SHFileOperation from the Windows API.  A reference to it is defined in ShellApi.  However, I would recommend looking into the [Jedi Code Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcl/).  The unit JclFileUtils contains a DeleteDirectory function which is much easier to use; it even has the option to send the deleted directory to the recycle bin.

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing wrong is using `DeleteFile` to delete something that isn't a file. [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363915.aspx) advises you:

> - To recursively delete the files in a directory, use the [`SHFileOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762164.aspx) function.
> - To remove an empty directory, use the [`RemoveDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365488.aspx) function.

The documentation doesn't explicitly tell you not to use `DeleteFile` on directories, but it's implied by those other two instructions.